# Arduino wifi > firebase and more than 1 LED control

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, arduino-esp8266

Can you please help me with below code. It works with 1 LED but not wit 2 LEDs / pins. On pin 3 works, but not on pin 5. Any suggestions?

I tried many different things but am stuck. Something isn't right inside loop. I think that will help many persons here on forum.

Snippet correction would be great or just tell me what to do for solving that problem.

**Arduino code:**

```c++
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>

// Set these to run example.
#define FIREBASE_HOST "test839785093353.firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "685g4d65d4g65d4g654TESTsf354s6f531sf531s"

//Change line with your WiFi router name and password
#define WIFI_SSID "Internet"  
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "password123123"


void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);

pinMode(5, OUTPUT);

// connect to wifi.
WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
Serial.print("connecting");

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
Serial.print(".");
delay(500);
}

Serial.println();
Serial.print("connected: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);

// ob povezavi inicializiras status
Firebase.set("LED_STATUS", 0);
Firebase.set("LED2_STATUS", 0);
}
int led1 = 0;
int led2 = 0;
// int led3 = 0;


void loop() {
// get value
led1 = Firebase.getInt("LED_STATUS");

led2 = Firebase.getInt("LED2_STATUS");

// handle error
if (led1==1) {
Serial.println("LED 1 ON");
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);  
return;
delay(10);
}
else {
Serial.println("LED 1 OFF");
digitalWrite(3,LOW);  
return;
}

   // se en if..else stavek
if (led2==1) {
Serial.println("LED 2 ON");
digitalWrite(5,HIGH);  
return;
delay(10);
}
else {
Serial.println("LED 2 OFF");
digitalWrite(5,LOW);  
return;
}


}
```

Comment: You to see `Serial.println("LED 2 ON");` happen?

Comment: In serial monitor i see only: "LED 1 OFF" and "LED 1 ON" after changing value in Firebase.

Comment: What's the point of the `return`s?

Comment: I'd say your `return'`s are not needed since you want to continue down the loop.

Comment: I've used Firebase for apps. I didn't realize there was an arduino library. Sweet.

Comment: Yes, it was `return's` problem. Now works, Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is the if else seatement that you have used for LED1. 
If `led1` is 1, it turns on led1 and exits the loop() function.
If `led1` is 0, it turns off led1 and exits the loop() function.

The code never reaches led2.

Try this change

```
if (led1==1) {
Serial.println("LED 1 ON");
digitalWrite(3,HIGH);  
delay(10);
}
else {
Serial.println("LED 1 OFF");
digitalWrite(3,LOW);  
}

   // se en if..else stavek
if (led2==1) {
Serial.println("LED 2 ON");
digitalWrite(5,HIGH);  
delay(10);
}
else {
Serial.println("LED 2 OFF");
digitalWrite(5,LOW); 
}
```

Comment: Now works perfectly with your code correction. Thank you!